# How to override all resources of spree including models ,controllers and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am using spree cms with rails 3.2 and successfully configure into my rails application.But i want to override all spree code including models ,controllers and views mean freeze spree gem into my app/vendor directory so that i can do any change according to my need and this change should apply to my app after start server.I am using this command but not work for me

```
             spree install --path vendor
```

Is there any better suggestions please advise.

Thanks a lot for any help...

Comment: Please explain why you would want to do something like this.

Comment: @RyanBigg  I want because of site like stickermule.com.So my customer section will entirely changed and also i don't want all products page.And also need to changed functionality a lot.

Comment: And currently i am doing like this  spree install --path vendor.But it is not optimized way because all gems are installed in my vendor directory.But in this way i can change every where in spree core and all changes are available to me.check my app if you have time here. ilsainteractive.com:3000

Answer (score 0):

This link you gives you exact answer for custom views

http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/view.html

For customizing models create a decorator file for your model(example: USER) in app/models/spree/user_decorator.rb

```
Spree::User.class_eval do
   Spree::PermittedAttributes.user_attributes << :your_custom_attribute


  def yourcustomfunction 
     # Your logic here
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the links provided below may be helpful for you ..  :)

http://serenetechnologies.ca/spree-e-commerce-customizations/

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html

Comment: could you add some general description on why and how